# Can we create unique_ptr using a lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Can I use a lambda as custom deleter. In fact, I use a C++ library in which a lot of class use a create/release API for instance life management (see example below)

```
class FileInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~FileInterface() {}

    virtual bool isValid() = 0 ;
    virtual void release() = 0;
};

class RealFile : public FileInterface
{
public:
    static int createFileInterface(const std::string& filename, FileInterface*& pFileInst) 
    {
        try {
            pFileInst = new RealFile(filename);
        } catch (...){
          return -1;
        }   
        return 0;
    }
    virtual bool isValid() { return (m_pFile != NULL);}
    virtual void release() { delete this;}

protected:
    RealFile(const std::string& filename) : m_pFile(NULL) { m_pFile = fopen(filename.c_str(), "wb"); if(m_pFile == NULL) {throw std::runtime_error("error while opening file.");} }
    ~RealFile() {
        std::cout << "DTOR" << std::endl;
        fclose(m_pFile); 
    }
private:
    FILE* m_pFile;
};
```

So to use that kind of class I need to handle by myself the `release` (at each return, throw etc... ).

```
FileInterface* pFile = nullptr;
int ret = RealFile::createFileInterface("test.bin", pFile);
std::cout << "isValid = " << pFile->isValid() << std::endl;
pFile->release();
```

So I would use a smart pointer to handle the create/release logic. My 1st step was to deal with the deleter and it's work fine

```
auto smartDeleter = [](FileInterface* ptr){ptr->release();};
FileInterface* pFile = nullptr;
int ret = RealFile::createFileInterface("test.bin", pFile);
std::unique_ptr<FileInterface, decltype(smartDeleter)> smartFile(pFile);
std::cout << "isValid = " << smartFile->isValid() << std::endl;
```

but in the 2nd step as I wrote a lambda for the create logic:

```
auto smartAllocator = [](const std::string& filename){
    FileInterface* pFile = nullptr;
    int ret = RealFile::createFileInterface(filename, pFile);
    if (ret != 0) return nullptr;
    else return pFile;
};
```

Compiler report errors:

```
CreateReleasePattern.cpp(65): error C3487: 'FileInterface *': all return expressions in a lambda must have the same type: previously it was 'nullptr'
1>CreateReleasePattern.cpp(65): error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'FileInterface *' to 'nullptr'
1>          nullptr can only be converted to pointer or handle typesCreateReleasePattern.cpp(65): error C3487: 'FileInterface *': all return expressions in a lambda must have the same type: previously it was 'nullptr'
1>CreateReleasePattern.cpp(65): error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'FileInterface *' to 'nullptr'
1>          nullptr can only be converted to pointer or handle types
```

How can I fix that ? is there a convertible operator that I could write on the FileInterface ?

Comment: FileInterface needs a virtual destructor.

Comment: @NeilKirk, I agree... I just rewrote here some piece of code to demonstrate and adding the virtual dtor will not solve the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lambda must specify its return type unless it consists of a single `return` statement. In future, these rules might be relaxed to allow multiple `return` statements; but even then, they will all have to be the same type, so that the function's return type is unambiguous. Your function returns either `nullptr_t` or `FileInterface*` depending on which `return` statement is reached.

Lambda syntax only allows trailing return types, so you want:

```
[](const std::string& filename) -> FileInterface* {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly and I understand the logic now, `nullptr_t` can be cast into a `FileInterface*` but the type must be set using that syntax to solve the ambiguity !